# Reinititalize 'str' as a type

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have used str as a variable. Now, I would like to convert an int into a string. For this, normally I would use str(10). What should I do in this case?

Comment: Restart python and don't use `str` as a variable name.

Comment: `'{}'.format(int_val)`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just delete the variable to get `str()` back:

```
othervarname = str
del str
```

Answer (score 1):

Find and replace "str" with "sensibleNameForYourVariable", then use `str(i)` to convert integers to strings.

Comment: It could be that before assigning it, he used it the proper way though.

Comment: Oh I see, I mistakenly assumed that he was writing a script.

Comment: Even if he was. Consider the following: `something = str(11)`, `str = 'this is a string'`. Finding all instances of `str` and replacing them with `'sensibleName'` will return a `NameError` upon running.

Comment: Fair point. We must hope that he hasn't written enough code to make manually checking `str`s an inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below if you had used str as a variable. This will solve your problem. The keyword str() internally uses `__str__()` function so better use that function only

```
str = 1
str.__str__()
```

**Output**

```
'1'
```

As in your case you should use.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve it from `__builtins__`.

```
str = "shadowed"
assert __builtins__.str(3) == "3"
```